Have tensegrity truss structures been proposed or deployed for space exploration, other than the Super Ball Bot?
Truss structures are used in space exploration for forming structures which are too large to be launched as deployed. For instance, this is a magnetometer boom undergoing  test deployment


https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11214-023-00989-5

Coilable Lattice Mast (components defined in the partially deployed
example shown here) forms the extendable Magboom structure used to
position the fluxgate sensors far from magnetic sources on Europa
Clipper.

Traditional trusses, as used in bridges and cranes, have compression and tension members joined together at nodes. But there is also a type of truss, the tensegrity truss, in which compression members are connected only to tension members, not to other compression members (discontinuous compression).

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/Tensegrity_simple_3.gif

The simplest tensegrity structure (a T3-prism). Each of three
compression members (green) is symmetric with the other two, and
symmetric from end to end. Each end is connected to three cables
(red), which provide tension and precisely define the position of that
end

Tensegrity trusses have some unusual properties including self-equilibration (distributing internal stresses across the structure.)
These properties were used to advantage in the design of NASA’s Super Ball Bot, an all-in-one landing and mobility platform based on tensegrity structure


allowing for lower-cost, and more reliable planetary missions.
Inspiration strikes from the most unlikely sources. Adrian Agogino and
Vytas Sunspiral of NASA’s Intelligent Systems Division and Fellows of
the NASA Innovative Advanced Concepts program (www.nasa.gov/niac) are
in the process of developing a Super Ball Bot–a collapsible,
terrestrial robot based on a tensegrity toy that could one day become
important to NASA’s exploration goals. These planetary surface
explorers are sturdier and can withstand a substantial impact. The
Super Ball Bot has a sphere-like matrix of cables and joints that
could withstand being dropped from a spacecraft high above a planetary
surface and hit the ground with a bounce. Once on the planet, the
joints could adjust to roll the bot in any direction while housing a
data collecting device within its core. The lighter weight and
maneuverability of the Super Ball Bot could make an exploration
mission possible to Saturn’s moon Titan. It has a soft planetary
surface more like hazardous marsh with lakes of liquid methane that
would not be suitable for a traditional rover that could sink down and
get stuck. https://www.nasa.gov/image-article/super-ball-bot




A design for a tensegrity mast is illusteated by this sculpture by Kenneth Snelson

This design has intriguing possibilities for launch storage and subsequent deployment in space. If some of the tension members had variable tension (as in the Super Ball Bot) the truss could be actively curved to control the position of the distal end.
Have tensegrity truss structures been proposed or deployed for space exploration, other than the Super Ball Bot?

some more extendable booms and what-not: answer to Does an umbrella reflector telescope exist? and How does IXPE measure polarization, and why does it have three identical X-ray telescopes? (I know there's even more here somewhere) I can see great promise for tensegrities -  large dishes that don't deform (in space or on the Moon) or remain homology telescopes when they do.

Tensegrity twisted prism in 3D, using SageMath
